# Does this sum converge?

Tags: summation

If I input:

```
Sum[Binomial[-1/2, n], {n, 0, ∞}]
```

MMA returns:

> Sum::div: Sum does not converge. >>

But I think that this sum does converge.  It is an alternating sum and the ratio of the absolute values of subsequent terms is less than 1.  In other words, the absolute values of the terms in the sum are decreasing.  It should converge between 1/2 and 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to figure out

In the documentation of [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) , under *Possible Issues* you can read :

> Sums may not be convergent, Using
>   [`Regularization`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Regularization.html)
>   may give a finite value.

[image]

### A solution example

```
Sum[
 Binomial[-1/2, n]
 , {n, 0, ∞}
 , Regularization -> "Abel"
 ]
```

> ```
> 1/Sqrt[2]
> ```

### Plot

```
ListPlot[
 Table[
  {k, NSum[Binomial[-1/2, n], {n, 0, k}]}
  , {k, 1, 1000}
  ]
 , Epilog -> {Blue, InfiniteLine[{0, 0.7071067811865475`}, {1, 0}]}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 , PlotRange -> {0.5, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]